# Command line input

Tags: java, grid, jframe, jpanel

Is there any way to get only the initial press from the drag, because right now it keeps toggling between black and white when dragged over the same square. Also, I am trying to get from the command line the width and height of the rectangles that will make the grid, if the user screws up or nothing is input then they are set to 50 by default. I tried creating a method because I didn't really know how to put them in the main an then use it in the JPanel.

```
public class Clicky extends JFrame {

private static class Board extends JPanel {

    public int BRICK_WIDTH = 50;
    public int BRICK_HEIGHT = 50;
    public Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    public double width = screenSize.getWidth();
    public double height = screenSize.getHeight();
    public double bWidth;
    public double bHeight;
    private int COLS = (int) (width / bWidth);
    private int ROWS = (int) (height / bHeight);
    private Color CO = Color.BLACK;

    private boolean[][] isWhite = new boolean[COLS + 1][ROWS + 1];

    public Board() {


        System.out.println("WIdth:" + COLS + "Height:" + ROWS);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                mx = e.getX();
                my = e.getY();
                System.out.printf("X: %d Y: %d ", mx, my);
                isWhite[(int) (mx / bWidth)][(int) (my
                        / bHeight)] = !isWhite[(int) (mx / bWidth)][(int) (my / bHeight)];
                repaint();
            }
        });

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                mx = e.getX();
                my = e.getY();
                isWhite[(int) (mx / bWidth)][(int) (my
                        / bHeight)] = !isWhite[(int) (mx / bWidth)][(int) (my / bHeight)];
                int gridx = e.getX();
                int gridy = e.getY();
                System.out.println(gridx);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g,String[] args ) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        drawBricks(g);
        getValues(args);
    }

    private double x;
    private double y;

    public void getValues(String[] args){
         try
         {
             bWidth = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
         }

         catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException | NumberFormatException ex)
         {
    // If the argument was bad then use the default.
         bWidth = BRICK_WIDTH;
         }

         try
         {
             bHeight = Integer.valueOf(args[1]);
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException | NumberFormatException ex)
        {
    // If the argument was bad then use the default.
         bHeight = BRICK_HEIGHT;
        }
}
       private void drawBricks(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D brick = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j <= ROWS; j++) {
            for (int a = 0; a <= COLS; a++) {
                if (isWhite[a][j]) {
                    brick.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                } else {
                    brick.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                }
                Rectangle2D.Double rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, bWidth, bHeight);
                brick.fill(rect);

                brick.setColor(Color.gray);
                brick.draw(rect);
                x += bWidth;
            }
            repaint();
            x = 0;
            y += bHeight;
        }

    }

    public int mx = -100;
    public int my = -100;
}

public Clicky() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // mai bine cu exit on close
    setSize(800, 820);
    add(new Board());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Clicky().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an event you can listen for that will tell you when the drag event starts. You can write one yourself. You'll need to some kind of stateful variable that can be toggled on the first receipt of a mouse dragged event then used as a guard for subsequent mouse dragged events. You can reset the stateful variable on a mouse release event. See [MouseEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html) and [MouseEventListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionListener.html).

As for your other question - I'm not really sure what you're asking. Are you wondering how to get user-supplied data from the command line or trying to figure out how to make use of them once they are supplied?

For the former it's dead simple with [command line arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html). For the latter, all you have to do is write a setter method that validates the input and overrides the default if caller-supplied values are valid.